# Derivative of definite integral of function of two variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know that the fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f(t)$ is differentiable on the interval $(a,x)$ for some constant $a$ and variable $x$ then we have

\begin{equation}\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt = f(x).\end{equation}

What I am wondering is, what happens when a function depends on $x$ as well? So, for example, $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. For concreteness perhaps say $g(x,t) = f(x-t)$. Then how do I compute

\begin{equation}\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x g(x,t)dt?\end{equation}

Comment: This is slightly unrelated, but you may find it interesting to look at the Leibniz Integral Rule, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule. This doesn't deal with integrals exactly of your kind since the upper limit isn't the variable of the derivative, but it's a nice rule in itself.

Comment: Completly related. It's a straight application of Leibniz rule.

Comment: Bill, I think Rafa is right, since the upper limit in Leibniz's rule is a function of x, we could just set it to x. If you post your comment as an answer (slightly edited) I'll accept.

Answer (score 4):

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

---

So, $$\begin{equation}\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt = \int_a^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t)+f( x) \frac{dx}{dx}-f( a) \frac{da}{dx}=0+f(x)-0=f(x)\end{equation}$$

As $\quad a\quad$ is constant,  $\quad\frac{da}{dx}=0\quad$ and as $\quad f(t)\quad$ is indepentent of $x$,  $\quad\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t)=0.$